# How to create parameterized localized strings in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to localize a string that says "Hello {0}" where {0} is the name of the user. I know how to partially do this; create a TextBlock in the XAML with x:Uid "Welcome" and then create a .resw file that includes a resource with name Welcome.Text and value "Hello {0}". But how can I shoehorn the user name into the {0}? Similarly, suppose I want a string like "Created on 3/2/2016" or "You earned $100.24" and I want to control the formatting of the specified value? My app is using MVVM and ideally I'd pull the parameterized values out of the model, but regardless, how am I supposed to construct these strings using something like string.Format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the string via code:

```
public static class ResourceRetriever
    {
        private static ResourceMap _resourceMap = null;
        public static ResourceMap ResourceMap
        {
            get
            {
                if (_resourceMap == null)
                {
                    _resourceMap=  Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap;                    
                }
                return _resourceMap;
            }
        }

        public static string GetString(string key)
        {
            return ResourceMap?.GetValue("Resources/" + key, new ResourceContext())?.ValueAsString;
        }

        public static string GetString(string key, ResourceContext context)
        {
            return ResourceMap?.GetValue("Resources/"+key, context)?.ValueAsString;
        }
    }
```

Add into resource files parameters, and use string.Format:

```
var myText = ResourceRetriever.GetString("MyText"); //Hello {0}
myText = String.Format(myText, username);
```

Comment: So in this scenario, I don't use the x:Uid mechanism to get the localized strings into the controls?

Comment: Yes in this case you don't use x:Uid

Comment: kind of ugly that a different approach is needed for strings with and without parameters. would be nicer if you could use databinding with a string formatter, and/or converters for this. so in the case of parameters, i'd use databinding and include the view model property in the binding expression. but if no parameter, i'm somehow bind to the RESW file.